# Putting getLocation() function and showPosition() illegal constructor

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am attempting to just put my getLocation() function and showPosition() function in a different file called location.js. But whenever I try to call the file from main.js it just says it's an illegal constructor

Stopwatch.js:

```
function Stopwatch(elem) {
  var time = 0;
  var offset;
  var interval;

  function update() {
    if (this.isOn) {
      time += delta();
    }

    elem.textContent = timeFormatter(time);
  }

  function delta() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var timePassed = now - offset;

    offset = now;

    return timePassed;
  }

  function timeFormatter(time) {
    time = new Date(time);

    var minutes = time.getMinutes().toString();
    var seconds = time.getSeconds().toString();
    var milliseconds = time.getMilliseconds().toString();

    if (minutes.length < 2) {
      minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }

    if (seconds.length < 2) {
      seconds = '0' + seconds;
    }

    while (milliseconds.length < 3) {
      milliseconds = '0' + milliseconds;
    }

    return minutes + ' : ' + seconds + ' . ' + milliseconds;
  }

  this.start = function() {
    interval = setInterval(update.bind(this), 10);
    offset = Date.now();
    this.isOn = true;
  };

  this.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
    this.isOn = false;
  };

  this.reset = function() {
    time = 0;
    update();
  };

  this.getLocation = function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        console.log("Not supported by this browser.");
    }
};

function showPosition(position) {
  console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude);
  console.log("Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
};

  this.isOn = false;
}
```

Main.js:

```
var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
var toggleBtn = document.getElementById('toggle');
var resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');

var loc = new Location(); //ILLEGAL CONSTRUCTOR?!
var watch = new Stopwatch(timer);

function start() {
  toggleBtn.textContent = 'Stop';
  watch.getLocation();
  watch.start();
}

function stop() {
  toggleBtn.textContent = 'Start';
  watch.stop();
}

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  watch.isOn ? stop() : start();
});

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  watch.reset();
});
```

location.js: this is where I want the getLocation to go from stopwatch

```
function Location(){
   this.getLocation = function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        console.log("Not supported by this browser.");
    }
};

function showPosition(position) {
  console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude);
  console.log("Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
};
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code with throws the error? Might help us understand your issue better.

Comment: In what sequence these files are added in HTML file?

Comment: @LloydFrancis there error states: Illegal Constructor thats all it gives me.

Comment: `this.getLocation` is a method of your `Stopwatch` class. You can not just rip it out of there, place it somewhere in the global scope - and then expect `watch.getLocation();` to still work.

Comment: @misorude im well aware of that. I changed watch.getLocation(); to location.getLocation(); and it still didn't work.

Comment: This seems to collide with an already existing object, `window.Location` – so chose a different name for your own location class.